# resignFirstResponder on UITextView - slowing down the disappearance of the keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, resignfirstresponder

I wonder is there any way to slow down the disappearance of a native keyboard in an iOS app when using `resignFirstResponder` on a TextView. The keyboard is going down too fast and I want it to go slower. Is that possible?

**EDIT:**
My context is this:
I add a new view on top of the current view and because of this, my keyboard disappears momentarily. 
That's how my code looks:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *tmpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [tmpButton setTitle:@"Tap me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tmpButton sizeToFit];
    [tmpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTestClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:tmpButton];
}


- (void) btnTestClicked{
    [tmpText resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I also have the view hierarchy like that:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1;
    return YES;
}
```

The app is real simple but the keyboards disappears very fast, not like when I don't have any other views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, I think:

```
- (void)btnTestClicked {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^(void){
            [tmpText resignFirstResponder];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
              //Do something
        }];    
    }
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, it slows down the **appearance** of the keyboard, not it's **disappearance**. The keyboard still just fades away, not roll down slowly like it should. Do you know why it's like that?

Comment: I've test, resignFirstResponder mean disappearance.

Comment: I know what it does, but the disappearance isn't slow. Maybe the reason is I have this thing in appDelegate? Check out my new edit, please

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's the purpose of "self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1"; But I delete it, it work OK.

Comment: It creates a new view on top of the StatusBar and unfortunately I can't delete it.

Comment: Without tha line of code it works, so I've accepted your answer!

Comment: I also check,self.window.windowLevel just work in range [-1:10]. I still not understand.Sorry,I don't have any new investigation.

Answer (score 2):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}completion:nil];
```

Comment: Sure, I tried everything. The problem is with the `self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1;`

Comment: can you please explain me what the mean of this line?

Comment: It's creating a view controller on top of the status bar to display something on it

Comment: now i tried your window line and with this line my code is not working... but without this line its working fine......

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21685/discussion-between-sergiusgee-and-rajneesh071)